# How to set command execution timeout for command executed in linux

Tags: linux

I have below shell script, cmdx is testtool command that waits untill the execution and once execution is completed next command echo "End test" is
executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting tests"
cmdx
echo "End test"
```

I need to set some hardcoded execution time(example: duration 60 mins) for cmdx. post 60 mins cmdx should be stopped and next command echo "End test" should be executed
Can you please help on how we can achive this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [timeout(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command.

```
timeout 3600 command arguments...
```

will kill `command` after 3600 seconds. You can select the signal with `-s` option.

Just note that because `timeout` is an external command, the `command` must be an external command (can't be shell function). If it isn't, you can have something like

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "--inner" ]; then
    multiple
    test
    commands
    …
else
    echo "Starting tests"
    timeout 3600 "$0" --inner
    echo "End test"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this is not the question, why not using a cron job `crontab -e` to execute the script?

```
 0 * * * * /bin/sh /path/myscript.sh #exec every 60mins
```